# Flutter: Refreshing a list API on select of a filter in the same page

Tags: flutter

I have a use case in Flutter, where I need to display a list from an API. Once a particular filter is selected in the page, the displayed list should be refreshed by firing a new API. Below is my source code where I am displaying a list from the API.

```
class _MyFieldReportForm extends State<MyFieldReport> {
  var myContext;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    myContext = context;
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      body: new FutureBuilder<List<ReportData>>(
        future: fetchProducts(new http.Client()),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);

          return snapshot.hasData
              ? createListView(snapshot, myContext)
              : new Center(child: new CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        child: new Icon(Icons.add),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FieldvisitForm()));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

After pressing any filter button I need to refresh this API with the new one. It would be great if someone could help me with a sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got to know the solution. It can be done by getting the list in

```
void initState() {
super.initState();
listFuture = fetchProducts(new http.Client());
```

}

and in setState, I am updating the list. Below is the complete code:

```
     Future<List<ReportData>> listFuture;
     body: new FutureBuilder<List<ReportData>>(
        future: listFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);

          return snapshot.hasData
              ? createListView(snapshot, myContext)
              : new Center(child: new CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
      ),

onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            refreshList();
          });

void refreshList() {
    listFuture = fetchProductsUpdate(new http.Client());
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

checkout [my repo](https://github.com/max963/image_api/), i've created a App class extending a statefull, and a widget stateless, it maybe will help you